# INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out. using C#

Tags: c#

I am using the API for WSDL when using the Login method gives me the error, 
"INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token, or user locked out."

I am using "Salesforce.com Enterprise Web Services API Version 44.0" version.

I checked the credentials that do the login and are correct, and the Password I add the "Security Token" but I still throwing that error.

below is the complete error :

```
**urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com:INVALID_LOGIN
An unexpected error has occurred: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at ImportLeadsIntoSF.sforce.SforceService.login(String username, String password)
   at ImportLeadsIntoSF.ServiceClient.login()**
```

Comment: Do you have the correct login endpoint configured for production versus sandbox?

Comment: May be user you trying to login  is locked out, unlock it, then retry

Comment: DO you have IP based login restrictions?

Comment: @rahulgawale I checked login with current user in https://login.salesforce.com/ and it worked.

Comment: @DavidReed can you please guide me how can i check endpoint in WSDL service reference ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal when i try to get token via REST APi then all my credentials work properly. and i got token from that. and then after i used that token with my password (Password + token) to login via SOAP service.

Comment: @HardikBodara Could you show us how you perform/configure the login in your question? I'm not a C# programmer or a SOAP expert but we might be able to spot your issue.

Comment: Below is the Code :

`private SforceService binding;

private bool login()
{ 
    binding = new SforceService();
    binding.Timeout = 60000; 
    LoginResult loginResult;
     try
     {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;                
        loginResult = binding.login(UserName, Password+token);
        return true;
     }
     catch (SoapException e)
     {
         Console.Write("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message);
         return false;
     }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. You just need to reset security token from your user via https://login.salesforce.com/ with the same credentials.

Please click **[here](http://www.ashishblog.com/integrating-salesforce-soap-api-using-c-net/)** to get complete example with screenshots.